# why is it not possible to use "jump and link" and "jump register" for recursion?

Tags: assembly

Hopefully this is the right place for my question. Why is it impossible to use these two instructions for 
recursively calling a sub-routine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did it say that?

Comment: us this generic or a specific instruction set?

Comment: Please tag this with a hardware tag.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Hehe, he literally added the tag [tag:hardware]. OP, you were supposed to tag what architecture you mean as “jump and link” can have different meanings on different architectures.

Comment: Hey @mbd...  Add a tag to indicate *which* hardware you are asking about... Not the tag `hardware`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you “jump and link,” the return address is stored in a register. If you “jump and link” again, the return address is overwritten with a new one, destroying the original return address and preventing the caller from returning.

You can use “jump and link” in recursive functions (or any functions that call other functions), but then you have to manually save the content of the link register onto the stack.